# Callback transformed to suspend function loops infinitely when runBlocking

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am rewriting a java class to kotlin replacing callback with a suspend function. This is my java code:

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class DeviceType {

public String manufacturer;
public String marketName;
public String model;

public DeviceType(String manufacturer, String marketName, String model) {
    this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
    this.marketName = marketName;
    this.model = model;
}

public DeviceType(){}

public DeviceType(Context context) {
    DeviceName.with(context).request(new DeviceName.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFinished(DeviceName.DeviceInfo info, Exception error) {
            if (error == null) {
                manufacturer = info.manufacturer;
                marketName = info.marketName;
                model = info.model;
            } else
                Log.e("DeviceType: ", error.getMessage());
        }

    });
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    if (model == null) {
        return "No device type recognized!";
    } else {
        if (marketName.equals(model))
            return manufacturer + " " +marketName;
        else
            return manufacturer + " " +marketName+ " (" +model+ ")";
    }
}
```

`DeviceName` class belongs to library [AndroidDeviceNames](https://github.com/jaredrummler/AndroidDeviceNames).

Below is my new code in Kotlin:

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
data class DeviceType(
    var manufacturer: String? = null,
    var marketName: String? = null,
    var model: String? = null
) {

    constructor(context: Context) : this(
        context.deviceType()?.manufacturer,
        context.deviceType()?.marketName,
        context.deviceType()?.model
    )

    override fun toString(): String {
        val stringSuffix =
            if (marketName == model)
                ""
            else
                " ($model)"

        return model?.let { "$manufacturer $marketName$stringSuffix" }
            ?: "No device type recognized!"
    }
}

/**
 * return DeviceType "from" UI Context
 */
fun Context.deviceType(): DeviceType? = runBlocking {
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        /*
        delay(1000L)
        DeviceType("Nokia","Banana","R2D2")
        ^
        This works!
        */
        DeviceName
            .with(this@deviceType)
            .awaitWith(this@deviceType)
        //  ^ that doesn't!
    }
}

suspend fun DeviceName.Request.awaitWith(context: Context): DeviceType? = suspendCoroutine { cont ->
    DeviceName.with(context).request { info, error ->
        if (error == null) {
            cont.resume(DeviceType(
                info.manufacturer, 
                info.marketName, 
                info.model
            ))
        } else
            cont.resumeWithException(Throwable(error.message))
                .let {
                    Log.e(
                        "FirebaseUserData",
                        "DeviceName.Request.awaitWith(): $error.message"
                    )
                }
    }
}
```

Executing `deviceType().toString())` in `MainActivity` makes infinite looping in `runBlocking()` function.
The fundamental question is of course "why my implementation of `awaitWith()` does not work?", but I am also interested, taking first steps in kotlin and coroutines, if I should provide additional solutions for exception handling, as I read the "coroutines may hide exceptions".

And one more question:

Is `Dispatcher.IO` here OK? `DeviceName` gets data from Google API json query.
Should I use that dispatcher type also for coroutines related to firebase DB?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, responding to the question's title, the loop is happening because the constructor is calling `Context.deviceType()` that calls `DeviceName.Request.awaitWith` that calls the constructor again:

```
cont.resume(DeviceType(
                info.manufacturer, 
                info.marketName, 
                info.model
            ))
```

The `Context.deviceType()` return a `DeviceType` by itself, but you desire to use it to configure each attribute in the initialization. Each DeviceType's attribute initialization instantiate a `DeviceType` which each attribute instantiate another `DeviceType` and so on....

---

Using `Dispatcher.IO` is OK and even desired when it comes to IO operations, like network, but you are not quite using it.

The `runBlocking` call blocks the current thread. The way you are using is like that:

```
## Assume we are on Thread (A)
fun Context.deviceType(): DeviceType? = runBlocking { ## Still in thread (A)

    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { ## Execute in an IO thread pool, but (A) is waiting
        DeviceName
            .with(this@deviceType)
            .awaitWith(this@deviceType)
    } ## Returns to thread (A)
} # Resumes Thread (A)
```

So, although this is kinda running in an IO dispatcher, the calling thread is blocked until the execution is finished, making it synchronous and indifferent.

Comment: I removed `Context.deviceType()` from the constructor class and deleted constructor and made this function public.
Executing that function loops in runBlocking anyway...

Comment: Could you post it?

Comment: Morover. If I remove `runBlock{}` and change `deviceType()` to `suspend` function `GlobalScope.launch{context.deviceType()}` works.

Comment: cool... but make sure that it isn't looping infinitely any more. It may still facing this issue, but now less noticeable once it's not blocking the thread.

Answer (score 0):

Actually my goal was to see the `deviceType()` function output in non-coroutine environment. This function will be used anyway in other suspend functions or coroutine scope.

This is `DeviceType` class with its public functions without additional constructor:

```
    @IgnoreExtraProperties
    data class DeviceType(
        var manufacturer: String? = null,
        var marketName: String? = null,
        var model: String? = null
    ) {
        override fun toString(): String {
            val stringSuffix =
                if (marketName == model)
                    ""
                else
                    " ($model)"

            return model?.let { "$manufacturer $marketName$stringSuffix" }
                ?: "No device type recognized!"
        }
    }

    fun Context.deviceTypeByRunBlocking(): DeviceType? = runBlocking {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            DeviceName
                .with(this@deviceTypeNoSuspend)
                .awaitWith(this@deviceTypeNoSuspend)
        }
    }

    suspend fun Context.deviceType(): DeviceType? =
        DeviceName
            .with(this@deviceType)
            .awaitWith(this@deviceType)

    private suspend fun DeviceName.Request.awaitWith(context: Context): DeviceType? =
        suspendCoroutine { cont ->
            DeviceName.with(context).request { info, error ->
                if (error == null) {
                    cont.resume(
                        DeviceType(
                            info.manufacturer,
                            info.marketName,
                            info.model
                        )
                        //.also{Log.d("TAG","Inside awaitWith(): $it")}
                    )
                } else
                    cont.resumeWithException(Throwable(error.message))
                        .let {
                            Log.e(
                                "TAG",
                                "DeviceName.Request.awaitWith(): $error.message"
                            )
                        }
            }
        }
```

Main Activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    GlobalScope.launch { Log.d("MainActivity", "${this@MainActivity.deviceType()}") }
    //^ this works

    Log.d("MainActivity", "${this.deviceTypeByRunBlocking()}")
    //^ this still does not, loops in joinBlocking(), isComplete = false
    }
}
```

I know that using GlobalScope is not recommended, but for testing it is fine for me.